# Spring Controller Tests failing randomly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

There is a project with 20 controllers approximately. Each controller has its corresponding test class.
When we try to add new controller tests classes, some of the previous  tests which were running fine, starts to fail randomly. If any controller test class is annotated with @Ignore, tests get back to normal.

This is the exception thrown by the failing tests:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@22f3fadf has been closed already.

Full log of one failing test:

> :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.3.RELEASE)
>
> 2019-07-04T13:01:50,325 INFO  [pool-1-thread-17]
>   o.s.b.StartupInfoLogger: Starting ZipCodeControllerTest on valhala
>   with PID 17817 (started by wblanck in /home/wblanck/Projects/project)
>   2019-07-04T13:01:50,325 DEBUG [pool-1-thread-17]
>   o.s.b.StartupInfoLogger: Running with Spring Boot v2.0.3.RELEASE,
>   Spring v5.0.7.RELEASE 2019-07-04T13:01:50,325 INFO  [pool-1-thread-17]
>   o.s.b.SpringApplication: No active profile set, falling back to
>   default profiles: default 2019-07-04T13:01:50,326 INFO 
>   [pool-1-thread-17] o.s.c.s.AbstractApplicationContext: Refreshing
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@a5a2b92:
>   startup date [Thu Jul 04 13:01:50 ART 2019]; root of context hierarchy
>   2019-07-04T13:01:50,448 INFO  [pool-1-thread-17]
>   o.s.b.f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor: JSR-330
>   'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
>
> 2019-07-04T13:01:50,772 INFO  [pool-1-thread-17]
>   o.s.w.s.h.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry: Mapped
>   "{[/error]}" onto public
>   org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
>   com.package.controller.WrongPathErrorController.badPathError(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
>   2019-07-04T13:01:50,772 INFO  [pool-1-thread-17]
>   o.s.w.s.h.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry: Mapped
>   "{[/api/users/{device}/zip-code],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}"
>   onto public
>   org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
>   com.package.controller.ZipCodeController.checkZipCode(java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String)
>
> ... more HandlerMethodMappings ...
>
> 2019-07-04T13:01:50,773 INFO  [pool-1-thread-17]
>   o.s.w.s.h.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry: Mapped
>   "{[/swagger-resources/configuration/ui]}" onto public
>   org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
>   springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.uiConfiguration()
>   2019-07-04T13:01:50,773 INFO  [pool-1-thread-17]
>   o.s.w.s.h.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry: Mapped
>   "{[/swagger-resources]}" onto public
>   org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity>
>   springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.swaggerResources()
>   2019-07-04T13:01:50,773 INFO  [pool-1-thread-17]
>   o.s.w.s.h.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry: Mapped
>   "{[/swagger-resources/configuration/security]}" onto public
>   org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
>   springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.securityConfiguration()
>   2019-07-04T13:01:50,824 INFO  [pool-1-thread-17]
>   s.d.s.w.PropertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping: Mapped URL path
>   [/v2/api-docs] onto method [public
>   org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
>   springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
>   2019-07-04T13:01:50,859 INFO  [pool-1-thread-17]
>   o.s.w.s.h.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping: Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico]
>   onto handler of type [class
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
>   2019-07-04T13:01:50,913 INFO  [pool-1-thread-17]
>   o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter: Looking for
>   @ControllerAdvice:
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@a5a2b92:
>   startup date [Thu Jul 04 13:01:50 ART 2019]; root of context hierarchy
>   2019-07-04T13:01:50,931 INFO  [pool-1-thread-17]
>   o.s.w.s.h.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping: Mapped URL path [/webjars/**]
>   onto handler of type [class
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
>   2019-07-04T13:01:50,931 INFO  [pool-1-thread-17]
>   o.s.w.s.h.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping: Mapped URL path [/**] onto
>   handler of type [class
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
>   2019-07-04T13:01:50,938 INFO  [pool-1-thread-17]
>   o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver: Detected
>   @ExceptionHandler methods in integrationExceptionHandler
>   2019-07-04T13:01:50,981 INFO  [pool-1-thread-17]
>   o.s.m.w.MockServletContext: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet ''
>   2019-07-04T13:01:50,981 INFO  [pool-1-thread-17]
>   o.s.w.s.FrameworkServlet: FrameworkServlet '': initialization started
>   2019-07-04T13:01:50,987 INFO  [pool-1-thread-17]
>   o.s.w.s.FrameworkServlet: FrameworkServlet '': initialization
>   completed in 6 ms 2019-07-04T13:01:50,995 INFO  [pool-1-thread-17]
>   o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup: Starting beans in
>   phase 2147483647 2019-07-04T13:01:50,995 INFO  [pool-1-thread-17]
>   s.d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper: Context refreshed
>   2019-07-04T13:01:50,995 INFO  [pool-1-thread-17]
>   s.d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper: Found 1 custom
>   documentation plugin(s) 2019-07-04T13:01:50,999 INFO 
>   [pool-1-thread-17] s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner: Scanning for
>   api listing references 2019-07-04T13:01:51,109 INFO 
>   [pool-1-thread-17] o.s.b.StartupInfoLogger: Started
>   ZipCodeControllerTest in 0.813 seconds (JVM running for 39.78)
>   2019-07-04T13:01:51,111 INFO  [pool-1-thread-17]
>   o.s.c.s.AbstractApplicationContext: Closing
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@40554129:
>   startup date [Thu Jul 04 13:01:42 ART 2019]; root of context hierarchy
>   2019-07-04T13:01:51,112 INFO  [pool-1-thread-17]
>   o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup: Stopping beans in
>   phase 2147483647 Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0,
>   Time elapsed: 14.141 s <<< FAILURE! - in
>   com.package.controller.ZipCodeControllerTest
>   testInexistentCheckZipCode(com.package.controller.ZipCodeControllerTest)
>   Time elapsed: 10.648 s  <<< ERROR!
>   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@22f3fadf
>   has been closed already   at
>   com.package.controller.ZipCodeControllerTest.testInexistentCheckZipCode(ZipCodeControllerTest.java:80)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@22f3fadf
>   has been closed already   at
>   com.package.controller.ZipCodeControllerTest.testInexistentCheckZipCode(ZipCodeControllerTest.java:80)

Tests are very similar, basically the common structure is:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)
public class ControllerTest {

    private static final String URL_TEMPLATE = ".....";

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @MockBean
    private Service service;

    private CustomParams params;
    private CustomRequest request;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        // initialize params and request ...
    }

    @Test
    public void methodOk() throws Exception {
        when(service.method(refEq(params))).thenReturn(RESPONSE);

        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(URL_TEMPLATE)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(request)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath(STATUS_MESSAGE_PATH, is(MESSAGE_CODE_OK)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath(STATUS_CODE_PATH, is(STATUS_OK.getStatusCode()))));
    }


    @Test
    public void badRequest() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(URL_TEMPLATE))
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
                .andExpect(jsonPath(ERROR_MESSAGE_PATH).isNotEmpty());
    }
```

Controllers have a structure like the following:

```java
@RestController
public class Controller {

    private Service service;

    @PostMapping(value = "/api/some-url", produces = {"application/json"})
    public ResponseEntity<CustomResponse> method(
            @RequestHeader("someheaders") Integer someHeaders,
            @RequestBody CustomRequest someBody) {

        CustomParams params = new CustomParams();
        params.setApplicationType(applicationType);
        params.someHeaders(someHeaders);

        return service.method(params);
    }
```

I can't understand the reason of the exceptions and the fact that they occur in different tests in each run.

I've changed classes and variable's names due to confidentiality.

Comment: Can you share the whole stack trace of the erro? There is some `WARN` on the log before the problem happens?

Comment: @Dherik, thanks for the response. I've added the log of one of the failing tests. There is no warn before the error.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [DirtiesContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html) annotation on your tests. This will assure you'll get clean context on each test and they will not not interfere with eachother

Comment: I tried this by extending from a BaseTest class which was annotated with @DirtiesContext without success.

Comment: See request in spring-framework, open since 2019: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/11545