# @DataJpaTest throws "Error creating bean with name 'jpaAuditingHandler'" occasionally

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

I have a bunch of `@DataJpaTests` as well a lot of `@SpringBootTests` and `@WebMvcTests`.

I also have `@EnableJpaAuditing` enabled.

When I run `@DataJpaTests` independently it's all fine, these tests run and pass successfully. But if I run **all** the tests at once, some `@DataJpaTest` throw occasionally the following:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaAuditingHandler': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@15405bd6 has been closed already
```

The problem is that I don't see a pattern here. Sometimes I get this exception, sometimes not. Some `@DataJpaTest` throw this exception, some not... So I'm not sure how to prevent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56893656/9753003) helped me to resolve my problem.

I created an abstract class:

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS)
public abstract class BaseDataJpaTest {}
```

And inherit all my `@DataJpaTest` from this class.
This way I get a fresh context before each test.